# Converting Date string to datetime in powershell

Tags: powershell, date

I'm having trouble figuring the cleanest way to convert a date from one format to the other.

The dates are formatted "Jul 29th, 2021" and I cant change this in the source as its a system output. When I try to convert to datetime it isn't valid.

if anyone has any idea id appreciate it. An example of one of the things i tried is below

```
    $date = "Jul 29th, 2021"
    $testConversion = [datetime]$date
    $testConversion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can have strings like `th`, `st`, `nd` or `rd` in there, always followed by a comma, the best thing to do is to use a regex `-replace` on these first and next use `[datetime]::PareseExact()`.

To demonstrate:

```
$dates = 'Jul 29th, 2021', 'Aug 1st, 2021', 'Sep 2nd, 2021', 'Oct 3rd, 2021'

foreach ($date in $dates) {
    [datetime]::ParseExact(($date -replace '((th|st|nd|rd),)?'), 'MMM d yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
}
```

If your culture (locale) is already set to `en-US`, you can set the third parameter to `$null`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the swift response. So to add this into a larger picture. I have a switch comparison in a for each loop doing some fun stuff with html in powershell 7.

It pulls it from a table on a site as a string. I then need to convert that to UK format.  Using your script to convert to yankee doodle first just to test reports an error.

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String 'Apr 6 2021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
I altered it to the below
```$date = [datetime]::ParseExact(($td -replace '(th|st|nd|rd),'), 'MMM dd yyyy', [cultureinfo]'en-US')```

Comment: @DrJekyll_XYZ Could work, but without seeing that 'whole picture' it is hard to see what you mean here.. The question was on how to turn a formatted date string into a real DateTime object. What you do with that afterwards is of no concern.

Comment: Sorry im not used to trying to put things in code blocks on this site so i hit enter by accident

Comment: `Apr 6 2021` does not contain ordinal abbreviations as the example in your question had.. Anyway, I have changed the regex for that and added `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`

Comment: No because the code removes it with regex. the input variable is done before the rest of the line so the process that errors see's the variable with the characters removed. The replace part works great, it just doesnt recognise the resulting string as a date format

Comment: You know what pal, that's my bad. when i typed it in i added a d into the format. Changing it to invariant culture worked great. 

Thank you so much for your help there.